# arduino mega overheat when connected to TFT 7" and TFT shield

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, lcd

I have bought a 7" LCD (`TFT01-7`) and a shield to make it work with arduino mega (http://www.elecfreaks.com/store/lcd-tft01-mega-shield-v10-p-214.html), but when I upload my code to the arduino and plug my LCD to the shield the arduino get overheated and the LCD lose power and I don't know why even when I power my arduino with external 9V 2A adapter, I even tried uploading an example from the library but it does the same, I used to work with the same code and the same shield but with 5" LCD `ITDB50` and I didn't have this problem before, how can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: What is powering the mega?

Comment: an external adapter (9V,2A)

Answer (score 1):

7" LCDs need a lot of current. They need it for the back light.

That current comes from the 5V pin.  That 5V pin is supplied by a linear regulator that has limited current capacity.  As you draw more current it gets hotter and hotter and eventually shuts down.

You will need to power your LCD screen with another external 5V source. The best solution may be a powerful (2A) phone charger (USB) which you then plug direct into the USB port of the board thus bypassing the weak regulator.

Comment: So can I connect my lcd to the shield and connect the 5V pin to external power source and then connect the ground pin to the external source ground and make it common with the arduino ground?

Comment: Yep. That's right. As long as it is a regulated 5V power source.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (I was buying some components), I did try what you said, I connected my LCD to the shield and connected it to arduino through jumpers, except for the (3.3V, 5V, ground, Vin) pins wich happen to be the power pins on the shield, I connected them to external (5V 1.5A) usb adapter, I think that the LCD is stable now but I only get the backlight on...I can't see my code, it doesn't draw anything.

Comment: Is the ground connected to both the Arduino and the external power supply?

Comment: I'm connecting Vin on the arduino board to 5V and whenever I take it off the LCD starts blinking, and I do connect the corresponding pin to Vin on the shield to 5v, I'm also connecting both the ground pins on the arduino and the corresponding pins to the on the shield to the ground of the 5V power source, the 3.3V corresponding pin on the shield is connected through a level shifter that I made of 10k and 20k resistors and connected them to the 5V adapter and finally the RST pin is connected to it's corresponding on the shield

Comment: `the 3.3V corresponding pin on the shield is connected through a level shifter that I made of 10k and 20k resistors` - that is doomed to failure. You cannot translate power that way, only very very tiny signals.

Comment: Ok, I moved it back to the arduino 3.3V pin but still nothing happens.

Comment: Please provide a picture or drawing of how you have it wired up at the moment. It is not clear from your description.

Comment: please check the edit that I did to my question